# SQL forum conversion script (IPB to SMF) is getting stuck

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm converting a forum currently running IPB 2.3.1 to SMF 2.0.13 (recommended that I used the slightly older version first) using the converter available at the SMF website. I've had to make a few small edits as it ran into errors, but my knowledge of sql coding before I started this was ZERO, so please speak verrrry slowly. :D We're on a shared server, so cannot change mySql to turn off strict mode, which has solved this issue for others (apparently) - so it's either fix the script or download everything and running it locally with strict mode off (no guarantees that would fix it either). Basically, it's now stuck with this error being reported:

> Converting permissions...Field 'description' doesn't have a default
>   value

Already edited the SMF table as per instructions given to me on the SMF forums (ran "alter table smf_boards change description description varchar(255) null default '';" - without the quotes) but that hasn't helped get things moving again - have restarted the conversion and it got stuck again at the same place.

The part of the script that has the issues:

```
SUBSTRING(description, 1, 65534) AS description,
```

I'll be very grateful for any help on this!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with either IPB or SMF, but from what you wrote, it looks like you trying to insert a string which is maximum 65534 long into a field which is 255. Maybe you should alter your column to be varchar(65534)

Comment: That's interesting - I would have tried that if I wasn't finished with the conversion now - I finally just took that bit of the script out, as it wasn't essential. I may add this info to the post at the SMF forums as a potential fix should anyone else have the same problem.